# Contacts Not Fetching On Physical Device-iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, testflight

I am currently trying to test out my iOS app with `TestFlight` and am running into a few issues with fetching contacts. My app is supposed to retrieve all the contacts in the contact book and then display them in a table view after checking firebase to make sure that the contact hasn't already been invited to the app. It works fine on the simulator that has 10 contacts but does not work at all on my phone with 100+ contacts. No contacts even appear. I have checked that I have contacts enabled as well. Not sure what the issue may be. I have attached the code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (success, error) in
        if success{
            print("Contact Authorization Successful")
        }
    }
    fetchContacts()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
func fetchContacts(){
    contacts = [ContactStruct]()
    let key = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: key)
    try! contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) { (contact, stoppingPointer) in
        let name = contact.givenName
        let familyName = contact.familyName
        let fullName = contact.givenName + contact.familyName
        let number = (contact.phoneNumbers[0].value ).value(forKey: "digits") as! String
        let contactImage = contact.imageData


        let phone = (contact.phoneNumbers[0].value ).value(forKey: "digits") as! String

            self.phoneNumbersArray.append(phone)


        let contactToAppend = ContactStruct(givenName: name, familyName: familyName, fullName: fullName, phoneNumber: number, contactImage: contactImage)

        self.contacts.append(contactToAppend)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    getAllUsers()
}


func getAllUsers(){
    self.sectionData = [0: self.contactsOnApp as Array<AnyObject>, 1: self.usersInSchool as Array<AnyObject>, 2: self.contacts as Array<AnyObject>]
    ref.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)
        let currentUserSchool = user.highSchool!

        for child in user.invitesFormatted {
            let checkInvites = child
                if let alreadyInvited = self.contacts.index(where: {$0.phoneNumber == checkInvites}){
                    self.contacts.remove(at: alreadyInvited)
                    self.sectionData = [0: self.contactsOnApp as Array<AnyObject>, 1: self.usersInSchool as Array<AnyObject>, 2: self.contacts as Array<AnyObject>]
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }

        ref.child("schools").child(currentUserSchool).child("members").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in

            for child in snap.children{

                let child = child as? DataSnapshot
                if let otherUsers = child?.key {
                    ref.child("users").child(otherUsers).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snappy) in
                        let personInSchool = User(snapshot: snappy)

                        if personInSchool.uid != uid! && self.phoneNumbersArray.contains(personInSchool.phoneNumber) {
                            //If contacts does have user
                            self.contactsOnApp.append(personInSchool)

                                if let itemToRemoveIndex = self.contacts.index(where: {$0.phoneNumber == personInSchool.phoneNumber}) {
                                        self.contacts.remove(at: itemToRemoveIndex)
                            }   
                        }else if personInSchool.uid != uid! {
                            //If contacts doesn't have user
                            self.usersInSchool.append(personInSchool)   
                        }
                        self.sectionData = [0: self.contactsOnApp as Array<AnyObject>, 1: self.usersInSchool as Array<AnyObject>, 2: self.contacts as Array<AnyObject>]
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to move the call to `fetchContacts` to be inside the completion handler for the call to `requestAccess` and only if `success` is `true`.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok I will try that, but why is it that it works on the simulator but not on the device?

Comment: You also have a lot of calls to `reloadData`. Why not just call it one time after all of the data is fully loaded?

Comment: @rmaddy Mainly because I am not sure when/where the data fully loads since the firebase functions are asynchronous. Is there a place you would add it? Also, do you happen to know why it still works on the simulator?

Comment: You probably granted access at some point. Delete and retest on the simulator or a real device. Do some debugging and see where things are not working as expected.

Comment: @rmaddy Moving the call to `fetchContacts` to be inside the completion handler actually causes my app to crash because it is not being called. Again, I tested my code on the simulator with just 12 contacts and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @rmaddy suggestions are on point. You should not perform tasks unless your app knows it has permission to do so. So the fetchContacts and tableView assignments should go within the *is success* closure. Also, you don't need to reload the tableView after each contact - load the array first *then* update the tableview. Also, the getAllUsers() function will probably execute before the contactsArray is populated which may be why it works for 12 and not for 100 (just guessing on that one)

Comment: @Jay Moved the calls to the closure and it still does not work on physical device. It still does work on the simulator though.

Comment: Can you change the print 'authorization successful' to maybe an alert so you can see if that's executing on a real device? Did you address the getAllUsers issue?

Comment: @Jay I changed it and the authorization is successful but only one contact shows up and it's the same one every time.

Comment: Note that *fetchContacts()* will probably be called before *contactStore.requestAccess(* has time to complete - not sure but it looks like it's asynchronous so it will take longer to execute than the code following it.

Comment: @Jay So I tested this on a few different devices and apparently it is only a bug on my phone, which is strange but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can only fetch contacts if the device has given the app access to do so. My guess is that you did not give the app access, therefore your fetchContacts() will never work.

Do a fresh install of the app on a real device. If you ask for permissions to use the users contacts correctly, then this should trigger the app to ask the use. Make sure the click yes on the popup message. You could also check the App Settings under the Settings app and re-enable the app to allow access to contacts.

[image: App Settings under the Settings app]

Comment: This is what I thought it was at first but I have checked multiple times even after deleting and reinstalling the app and contacts have been enabled each time.

Comment: @A.Albert have you found solution I'm facing same issue?